# converting a column to integer in pandas to prepare for regression

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing data for regression but i couldn't do it. I have to covert 2 rows likes and popularity to integer. how can i do it.

```
Unique_ID      int64
Genre          int64
Views          int64
Comments       int64
Likes         object
Popularity    object
Followers      int64
dtype: object
```

1.I did this:

```
df['Popularity']=df.Popularity.str.replace(',','').astype(int)
```

and error came

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '13.1K'

2. then I tried this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Likes'], downcast='integer')
```

again error came

> Unable to parse string "2,400" at position 3

3. and this as well

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,400'

what can i do so that i can do regression to my data

Comment: `df[column] = df[column].astype(int)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: could you post a sample of data columns you are trying to convert?

Comment: you can checkout the data from here https://www.machinehack.com/course/chartbusters-prediction-foretell-the-popularity-of-songs/ I was working on the training set.

Comment: @subhashi - I want to retain the information of K and M in my data , i dont want to remove them. I want to make a function which will automatically convert K and M in the respective positions with 1000 and 1000000.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some entries of format `13.1K` so you should have to strip them from last `K` as well.

```
df['Property'] = df['Property'].str.replace(',','')
df['Property'] = df['Property'].str.rstrip('K')
```

If there are other characters as well like `M` strip them or use regex to find them and then convert them to `float`.

```
df['Property'] = df['Property'].astype('float64')
```

You can also do this to remove any alphabet from last as follows:

```
from string import ascii_letters
df['Property'] = df['Property'].str.rstrip(ascii_letters)
```

**EDIT**

As per OP's requirement asked in the comments,below solution will work.

Assuming original data-set have values like this:

```
0   13.1K
1   2,400
2   4555
3   6,1M
4   6.1M
```

Using following code

```
df['Property']=df['Property'].str.replace(',','')
df.['Property'] = (df.['Property'].replace(r'[KM]+$', '',regex=True).astype(float) * \
              df.['Property'].str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
                .fillna(1).replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))
```

Will transform the data as follows

```
0   13100.0
1   2400.0
2   4555.0
3   61000000.0
4   6100000.0
```

Comment: i dont want to strip them. I want to put 1000 where there is K and 1000000 where there is M to all my data. Thankyou

Comment: MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (54920, 40658) and data type int64
​then i tried echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory   zsh: permission denied: /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory

Comment: `MemoryError` is out of scope of this question, but you should use `sudo` or login as `root` and it can do the trick. fe days back i literally ha this problem and these SO posts helped me: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type 2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812453/memoryerror-unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type-object

Comment: tried the sudo method but it didn't work.i tried this sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches but still couldn't do anything.same error is coming

Comment: Depends on your ram, i do think after over commit the error figure `shape (54920, 40658)` would have gone down. but your memory is still unable to handle such large data set you can try reducing the size of your data set.

Comment: @Himanshu, consider green ticking the solution so this can be closed =)